# Dividing 2 numbers

Tags: c++, exception-handling

The problem is to input, divide 2 `int`s and display the result.
Please, review my program. It worth noting, I've intentionally used `goto`, not `while`.

```
int main(){
    int a, b;

ab_input:
    cout << "Enter 2 numbers: ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    try {
        if (!cin) throw std::runtime_error("Bad input");
        if (b == 0) throw std::runtime_error("Dividing by zero");
    } 
    catch (std::runtime_error er) {
        cin.sync();
        cin.clear();
        std::cerr << er.what() << endl;
        cout << "Try again? y/n: ";
        char c; 
        cin >> c;
        if (cin && c == 'y') goto ab_input;
        else return -1;
    }
    cout << "a/b = " << a / b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you've intentionally used `goto`?

Comment: [Hope the raptors get you](http://xkcd.com/292/) ... ;-) ....

Comment: (LET THE HOLYWAR BEGINS!!!11) I believe it's more apropriate and more readable here, than `while`. Or `goto`_is_bad is a dogma? Anyway, may be there are some another notes?

Comment: My C++ is a bit rusty, what if the user writes a number larger than 2^31-1? Doesn't that result in an overflow and a wrong result? OR does the !cin catch that?

Comment: You should also be catching the `std::runtime_error` by `const&`.

Comment: like `catch (const std::runtime_error &er)`?

Comment: "Or goto_is_bad is a dogma?" -- It's popularly [Considered harmful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful).

Comment: @user2198121: Yes.

Comment: @user2198121: Its not a holy war. That implies there are two large factions that disagree. I think you will find there is only one large faction (that war was won by our side decades ago). But yes there are legitimate uses of goto (they do exist and I have used goto once). But here it is not legitimate and does make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some alternatives to `goto`:

```
int main(){
    int a, b;

    for (;;) { // until success
        cout << "Enter 2 numbers: ";
        cin >> a >> b;
        try {
            if (!cin) throw std::runtime_error("Bad input");
            if (b == 0) throw std::runtime_error("Dividing by zero");
            break; // success!
        } 
        catch (const std::runtime_error& ex) {
            cin.sync();
            cin.clear();
            std::cerr << ex.what() << endl;
            cout << "Try again? y/n: ";
            char c; 
            cin >> c;
            if (cin && c == 'y') continue; // try again!
            else return -1;
        }
    }
    cout << "a/b = " << a / b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

or:

```
static bool tryAgain(const char* errorMessage){
    cin.sync();
    cin.clear();
    std::cerr << errorMessage << endl;
    cout << "Try again? y/n: ";
    char c; 
    cin >> c;
    return (cin && c == 'y'); // try again!
}

int main(){
    int a, b;

    const char* errorMessage;
    do {
        cout << "Enter 2 numbers: ";
        cin >> a >> b;
        // set errorMessage.
        if (!cin) errorMessage = "Bad input";
        else if ((b == 0)) errorMessage = "Dividing by zero";
        else errorMessage = 0;
        if (errorMessage && !tryAgain(errorMessage)) return -1; // fail!
    } while (errorMessage);
    cout << "a/b = " << a / b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
int main(){
    int a, b;

    for (;;) { // Until explicit break on success.
        cout << "Enter 2 numbers: ";
        cin >> a >> b;
        // set errorMessage.
        const char* errorMessage;
        if (!cin) errorMessage = "Bad input";
        else if ((b == 0)) errorMessage = "Dividing by zero";
        else break; // success!
        if (!tryAgain(errorMessage)) return -1; // fail!
    }

    cout << "a/b = " << a / b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also you might like to change the last statement to:

```
cout << "a/b = " << (double)a / b << endl;
```

> I would also mention that returning -1 is normally a bad idea. The shell interprets negative numbers in weird ways

All of the [Exit status - References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#References) suggest `0` for success and non-zero (but positive) for failure:

- Some (Unix and DOS) references suggest that the range of valid codes is `0..255`
- Another (HP OpenVMS) says that bits 29..31 are reserved and must be zero
- The Windows [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx) range up to 15999 (I guess you might want to return something like `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`).

Comment: I would also mention that returning -1 is normally a bad idea. The shell interprets negative numbers in weird ways